# can open header file, still file not found

Tags: c++, mingw, eclipse-cdt

Within Eclipse I'm using the `#include <sql.h>` library. When I build my project I'm getting the error of `No such file or directory`. When I want to open the declaration of `sql.h` it opens the header file, assuming Eclipse knows where to look for the header file.

I'm using Eclipse CDT and MinGW, assuming this is installed correctly..

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse knows about `sql.h` independently of your toolchain.

You must tell your compiler (MinGW) where the `sql.h` header is, and your linker where the `.lib`/`.a` library binary is.

- in `Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Compiler >> Includes` you put the path to the `.h`
- in `Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Linker >> Libraries` you put the path to the `.lib`/`.a`

Comment: This is assuming your Eclipse project is a managed build project. If it's a makefile project, you would add a `-I <path>` flag to the relevant part of the makefile.